# Adjusting the range per iteration in a Macro VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a huge dataset consisting of multiple choice questions, which have to be sorted. Each question consists of a group of 10 rows, which has to be transformed into 10 columns. The sheet is now 1100 rows and I will have to do this with 16 other sheets of the same format.

I have created a macro in Excel by recording the necessary actions which result in this line of code:

```
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("C21:C26").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C19").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
Rows("21:31").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("B27").Select
End Sub
```

Now I need the variables in the macro to change +1 each iteration, so the next iteration it will look like this.

```
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
Range("C22:C27").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("C20").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False _
    , Transpose:=True
Rows("22:32").Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("B28").Select
End Sub
```

I'm completely stuck there. Help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: I guess you mean transpose to columns. You are actually deleting 10 rows but transposing 5. Not transposing 10. Is that correct? And is your stated pattern above taking account of your deletions? i.e. Range("C22:C27").Select is correct for second iteration?

Comment: Yes, that is true, the last 5 rows are information that is not needed for the format I need the questions to be in. When I adjusted the range manually it worked perfectly, so the +1 is correct.

Comment: Is 1100  the last row in the sheet? last row in column C? Or are there 1100 rows from (including C21) to the end of the range you are interested in?

Comment: 1056 is the last row in the sheet overall.

Comment: How do you get the 1100 rows then?

Answer (score 1):

So I am a little unclear on your row counts.

You might be able to use arrays as follows (be sure to back up sheet as this clears data from the sheet)

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Test()
    Dim startRow As Long, endRow As Long, rng As Range, arr(), outputArr(), i As Long
    startRow = 21
    endRow = 1100

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetA") '<== Change as required
        Set rng = .Range("C" & startRow & ":C" & endRow)
        arr = rng.Value
        arr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(arr, 0, 1))
        ReDim outputArr(1 To 5, 1 To Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(UBound(arr, 1) / 5, 0))

        outputArr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(outputArr)
        Dim counter As Long, counter2 As Long
        counter2 = 1
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr) Step 12
            For counter = 0 To 4
                outputArr(counter2, counter + 1) = arr(i + counter)
            Next
            counter2 = counter2 + 1
        Next

        rng.ClearContents
        .Range("C19").Resize(UBound(outputArr, 1), UBound(outputArr, 2)) = outputArr
    End With
End Sub
```